# How can I damage or break a foe's weapon?

Tags: combat, weapons, system-introduction, l5r-4e

Can someone provide a step-by-step walkthrough of how to make an attack against a foe's weapon?

I wasn't able to find the specifics maneuvers and descriptions on official L5R 4E material (only some house rules on the internet).

In case there aren't any official rules on the matter, could anyone redirect me to the best house rules on the subject? I don't want to suggest broken mechanics to our GM...

Comment: **Note to potential answerers**: As indicated by the tags, the question is about the game *Legend of the Five Rings* and not D&D. We have already deleted a number of answers that assume this is about D&D and don't need more. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

**Disarm**

The Disarm maneuver is the most accurate way to depict a strike against the weapon within the existing system as indicated by the following line.

> Weapons with wooden components that are the target of a Disarm Maneuver by weapons with a steel blade may be broken, at the GM's discretion.

Obviously your GM can use his own discretion to extend this to other weapon interactions, although the chance that a flawless blade would shatter seems somewhat slim. I would personally choose to apply the "Rule of Cool" but your GM might opt to set a damage threshold. Although not a bad tracking method, something like giving the items Wounds and Reduction will tend to get cumbersome, especially in large fights.

Answer (score 1):

In the *Book of Water, pg31* I found a sidebar:

> **Peasant Weapon Quality**
>
> Compared to the weapons crafted specifically for
> samurai to use in battle, peasant weapons are generally
> of much lower quality. Many of the peasant weapons
> in the L5R 4th Edition Core rulebook include rules
> to represent this. For peasant weapons which do not
> already have such an entry in the core rulebook, a good
> rule of thumb is that the weapon will break if it does
> more than 20 points of damage in a single attack.
> This is not to say that peasant weapons are all fragile
> or shoddily made. Many of them, especially those crafted
> from metal, can last for many years or even decades of
> hard use at their intended tasks. Peasant blacksmiths
> take as much pride in their craftsmanship as any other
> Rokugani, after all. Moreover, they could if necessary
> craft peasant weapons with much more resilient
> components. Even a parangu can hold up better if it is
> crafted from higher-quality steel. The GM should feel
> free to modify or ignore the rules for peasant weapons
> breaking if the circumstances seem appropriate.

Otherwise I haven't found anything specific for item durability beyond *Great Clans pg31* where they describe structure wounds/reduction.  The *Book of Air pg176* includes suggestions for ways to include called shots in attacks, which has knocking items away (thus actually hitting the weapon in question).  Otherwise I have found no mention, not even in the Alternate Weapon Forging in *Secrets of the Empire pg240*

Answer (score 0):

I do not recall there be rules about breaking items in the core book (and I do not have it with me) however, I believe the way it would be handled would be via damage reduction and wounds.

This is due to the following, from the book of earth:
Groves of Stone
Area of Effect: Circular barrier 15’ in radius
... It entreats the Earth spirits
to draw an array of huge stones up from the ground,
erupting in an instant through most intervening physical
obstacles (such as the floor of a house) to create a circular
barrier around the caster. The stones are too strong to
break through with anything short of a siege engine
(**against a siege engine they are considered to have 500
Wounds and Reduction 15**)...

This suggests that objects that can be broken most likely have a DR and Wound Level that can be broken with either specialized tools, or appropriate weapons.

Comment: Great Clans page 31 includes structure durability.